# How to remove Blend for Visual Studio Express 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently was trying to download Visual Studio Express and I mistakenly downloaded the Blend for Visual Studio Express 2015 which seems to be for Windows apps. I then downloaded the correct one which is Visual Studio Express for Desktop. It is now taking up 11 GB (although some of it may be being used by Desktop one as well) of my sweet SSD storage.

How can I fully remove the Blend for VS 2015 as there seems to be no uninstall in the control panel (I am guessing I will forcefully have to remove everything and re-install the desktop one again).

Comment: While I personally haven't removed this component, the general theme of the Visual Studio installer is that you check boxes for things you want installed and you UNcheck the boxes for things you don't...  So, logically, just running the Microsoft Visual Studio installer from within Programs and Features (selecting "Change") then unchecking the box next to the component you want to remove should do the job.

Comment: Actually this indeed solved the problem. When I clicked change, there was an option for uninstall. Don't know why I hadn't tried doing it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 24):

In "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\"
search for "Blend" then you can find Blend_Core and Blend_LP directories.

In these directories, right-click Blend_Core.msi and Blend_LP.msi then click Uninstall.

Comment: The package names were `ModernBlend_Core_net.msi` and `ModernBlend_LP_net.msi` in my case.